# What is rolling mean and standard deviation in terms of stationarity?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, mean, stationarity, moving-window

I would like to know what a rolling mean and rolling S.D means in terms of achieving stationairty concerning a time series?

I ran an ADF test and it told me my time series was stationary however, by having a rolling mean and rolling S.D on my differences series, despite ADF telling me it’s stationary I DON’T have a constant rolling means or rolling S.D.

Comment: Note: The ADF test does not tell you whether a series is stationary

Answer (score 4):

Stationarity is a statistical property. As such, it is *exact* and *always holding* **only** in terms of the theoretical expected values through which we express it. For example, it is about having

$$E(X_t)= c,\;\;\ \forall t$$

But "rolling means" are rolling *sample* means, say

$$\bar X_{t-k , t} = \frac {1}{k+1} \sum_{j=t-k}^t x_j \;\;\;\bar X_{t-k+1 , t+1} = \frac {1}{k+1} \sum_{j=t-k+1}^{t+1} x_j$$

Being sample means, they never equal exactly the theoretical value they measure, $E(X_t)$ in our case.

Khinchin's Law of Large Numbers in fact tells us that the sample mean will be equal to the true expected value, only if the sample size becomes infinite (and only in probability).

It follows that two consecutive sample means are not expected to be equal (or any two for that matter). In fact, if you would get that rolling sample means are exactly equal, you should be alerted, because it would indicate that the process is not stochastic after all but deterministic, and in a very specific way.